# Will multiple SQL records require more memory than multiple fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, normalization, forms

**Situation:** SQL data storage for HTML form submissions.

**Scenario 1:**
1 table with each form field as a table field (form).

[image]

**Scenario 2:**
2 tables - 
1st table with id and timestamp (form_submission).
2nd table with id, fk to form_submission, field_title, field_value (form_field).
Only inserts data if the HTML field **has a value**.

[image]

**Which requires more memory?**

In scenario 1... only 1 record per submission, but each record will have multiple null values.

In scenario 2... 5+ records from the form_field table as well as the time submitted from the form_submission table.

*Side note:* we only get ten-thousands of form submissions per year.

Comment: Assuming the majority of users fill out the majority of fields, then yes, the more normalized form will take more memory (especially because of the timestamp - which I'm really hoping is a `DATETIME`/`DATETIME2`, and that's a terrible name for it, regardless).  Personally, for a HTML submission form (that doesn't have 'child' data), I'd probably do a single table for the form;  EAV tables can be much more difficult to query.  If you're building a more complex system though (like customer management), you're going to need to split things differently.

Comment: Thanks Clockwork... and yes it is a DATETIME type. I would mark your comment as answered if I could.

Comment: I changed "timestamp" to "submitted" per your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Yes, `submitted` is a much better name, although it implies boolean or similar state (submitted/pending, etc).  Perhaps `submittedAt`?  Always attempt to name variables by _use_, not by type (although there are certain domains where it may be awkward to _not_ include the 'type', such as 'soldOnBusinessDay' - which isn't _quite_ the same thing as a calendar day....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the majority of users fill out the majority of fields, then yes, the more normalized form will take more space/memory (especially because of the timestamp - which I'm really hoping is a `DATETIME`/`DATETIME2`, and that's a terrible name for it, regardless).

Personally, for a HTML submission form (that doesn't have 'child' data), I'd probably do a single table for the form; EAV tables can be much more difficult to query. Non-required columns can simply default to null.  If you're building a more complex system though (like customer management), you're going to need to split things differently.